# Is it possible to access the song name of the currently playing song in the Spotify Mac app via Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify, spotify-desktop

Is it possible to access the song name of the currently playing song in the Spotify Mac app via Applescript? I would like to be able to copy the name of the currently playing song to my clipboard.

If not possible through Applescript how else could I do this?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Spotify"
    set nowplaying to the current track's name
end tell

set the clipboard to nowplaying
```

Even though `set the clipboard` is a *Standard Additions* command, ordinarily one ought to be able to combine the above into a single line:

```
tell app "Spotify" to set the clipboard to the current track's name
```

but this appeared not to work on my system.  However, placing the clipboard command outwith the *Spotify* `tell` block works fine.

Comment: The second example can not work because "current track" is a property defined by the Spotify app, so it has no meaning outside of a ** tell application Spotify**  block.

Comment: @RonReuter I’ve edited the answer to illustrate my point a bit more clearly.

Comment: @CJK, I do not have Spotify but curious to know if this works: `tell application "Spotify" to set the clipboard to (get name of current track)` Even if it does though, sometimes I try to keep some things from Standard Additions outside of another app's `tell` _block_. Usually the ones that throw a non-fatal error when run in Script Editor's Events pane. Like the one I mentioned to wch1zpink the other day, it had two non-fatal errors when run within app's `tell` _block_.  Substituting "iTunes" in this _command_ worked  for me without errors while a track was playing.

Comment: @user3439894 Just tested it and you’re right, using `get` does, indeed, work.  I agree with you about trying to keep application and scripting additions commands separate where possible, as it seems like good practice to do so.  But your point about non-fatal errors is further justification as every error thrown takes time for AppleScript to recover before continuing with execution and, in theory at least, reduces efficiency of a script.

Comment: Both of these variants work: `tell application "Spotify" to set the clipboard to (get name of the current track)` as @CJK and @user3439894 said, and `tell application "Spotify" to set the clipboard to (name of the current track as string)`. What's going on is that `name of the current track` is evaluated to an AppleScript _reference_, not a string. The interpreter needs additional syntax to tell it to resolve the reference and produce a string. In the first example, the `get` causes evaluation of the reference, and in the second example the `as string` causes the evaluation.